# JavaScript and Tail Call

Tags: javascript, algorithm, v8

According to the v8 ticket, it said

Tail call elimination isn't compatible with JavaScript as it is used in the real 
    world.  Consider the following:

```
function foo(x) {
  return bar(x + 1);
}

function bar(x) {
  return foo.arguments[0];
}

foo(1)
```

This returns 1.

It didn't explain clearly what if JavaScript support tail call, what would be the value of foo(1) and why?

Anyone can explain?

Comment: for reference, http://markmail.org/message/tzlbsdo2tvxy7q4f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It didn't explain clearly what if JavaScript support tail call, what
>   would be the value of foo(1) and why?

The value will be `1` when you do `foo(1)` because `foo` function returns the result of `bar` function and `bar` function does nothing but read the first argument of `foo` function with `foo.arguments[0]` (`arguments` is implied object available to every function which is used to read arguments passed to function) and return it. The first argument of `foo` happens to be `1` when you do:

```
foo(1);
```

Here is break-down:

```
function foo(x) {
  return bar(x + 1); // foo calls bar function which returns 1
}

function bar(x) {
  return foo.arguments[0]; // bar reads first argument passed to foo which is 1
}

foo(1); // 1 is x in foo function
```

The `bar` function just reads first argument of `foo` (via `foo.arguments[0]`) and returns it because of which no addition is done.

Answer (score 4):

This deserves a bit of explanation. The conversation started like this (code reformatted):

> If I open the JavaScript console in Chrome and write this:
>
> ```
> function fac(n, a) { 
>     if (n == 0) { 
>         return a; 
>     } 
>     else { 
>         return fac(n - 1, a * n);
>     } 
> }
> fac(100000, 1);
> ```
>
> I get this: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> I think V8 might be a nice target virtual machine for other programming
>   languages if it supported tail calls. It's the only big obstacle I can see
>   for languages with functional features.

If you test the code, you'll notice that `fac` works for low values, returns `Infinity` for higher values and causes the browser to throw a `RangeError` (Maximum call stack size exceeded) for even higher values.

The reason for this is every function called from within another function is added to a "call stack," which involves some memory overhead. With enough recursion, the environment would run out of memory.

---

This is made to work in other languages by "tail call elimination," or removing the need to add the calls to the call stack. For example, function-like things can exist that are different from normal functions in that when they return, they cause the calling function to return. This can eliminate the need to add to the call stack, meaning recursion can be essentially infinite. See the [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) article on Wikipedia for an in-depth explanation.

The response to the message above simply provided a reason why tail-call elimination (dropping the functions from the call stack) would not be compatible with other features `(Function#arguments)`, ableit non-standard ones.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, tail call elimination is an optimization technique to save stack space, especially useful for recursion. When a function ends with a call to another function, tail call elimination can avoid allocating another stack frame to invoked the called function. Instead it will reuse (destroy and repurpose) the stack frame of the calling function since it is (presumably) no longer needed. However, the example shows that JavaScript code might still need the caller's stack frame.

> It didn't explain clearly what if JavaScript support tail call, what
>   would be the value of foo(1) and why?

If tail call elimination were supported, the information about the `foo` invocation would be destroyed when making the tail call to `bar`, so `foo.arguments[0]` would be an error. If the given code is to work, then tail call elimination is not possible.